# Вывод произовльного содержания ДО блока комментариев в single.php в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь вывести содержимое произвольного поля (Advanced custom fields) в шаблоне одиночной записи. Делаю так:
    <?php get_header(); ?>

```
        <!-- begin content  -->
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-page">

            <?php the_post(); ?>

                <div class="content-main">
                    <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                    <?php the_content(); ?>

                    <?php the_field('code'); ?> //ВЫВОД СОДЕРЖИМОГО ПРОИЗВОЛЬНОГО ПОЛЯ

                </div>
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            </div>                
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

В итоге содежимое выводиться, но почему то ПОСЛЕ блока комментариев.

Нашел способ вывода контента такой:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'add_text_to_content');
function add_text_to_content($content){
    $out = $content . "тест";
    return $out;
}
```

Выводит "тест", до комментариев, как и нужно. Как подставить значение произвольного поля вместо текста?

Сделал так:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'add_text_to_content');
function add_text_to_content($content){
    $mycode = the_field('code');
    $out = $content . $mycode;
    return $out;
}
```

Выводит содержимое, НО - в самом начале поста!

Answer (score 1):

```
<? if(have_posts()): ?>
   <? the_post() ?>
    <h1>
      <a href='<?=the_permalink()?>'><?=the_title()?></a>
    </h1>
    <? _e("Posted "); ?> by <? the_author(); ?> at
    <? the_time('F js, Y') ?>
    <? the_content("more"); ?>
<? //здесь  попробуйте вставить доп поле?>
<? comments_template(); ?>   
<? endif; ?>
```